# Inkscape - is it possible to make path intersection affecting only one of paths?

Tags: inkscape, clipping-mask

I want to intersect path A with path B that would

- modify path A to such intersection
- will not affect at all path B

I know about Path -> intersection but that affects both paths.

I know about [Object -> clip -> set](https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clipping-and-masking.html) but it is just applying clip operation rather than actually removing content outside image. And it anyway affects both paths.

My current hacky solution is to copy path that I want to preserve, and later try to move it into the same location - which often results in moving to sort-of-the same position what is not desirable.

I am attaching below what I would want achieve: keep yellow star shape unmodified, turn red rectangle into intersection of this rectangle and path.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the yellow star shape, press Ctrl+D. It generates a duplicate of the star and the duplicate only remains selected. Nothing moves. Bring the duplicate to top if that's needed. Just after Ctrl+D it is automatically on the top, but that can get changed if you do not use the duplicate straight away after it's created. Use the duplicate to make the intersection or other boolean operations. The original stays intact.

Save your nerves and learn to use the Objects panel to see the layering order, to see what's selected, to change the layering order and to make new selections. There you can also lock and hide shapes and reach pieces inside groups.

Comment: Is this Ctrl+D action reachable somehow via menus? (I will likely forget exact shortcut but maybe will remember where it can be found, as I do something in Inkscape only occasionally)

Comment: Ctrl+D is the default keyboard shortcut for Edit > Duplicate.

Comment: @reducingactivity: Or you can right click on an object and select Duplicate.